# RewriteRule trigger 404 when given too many arguments

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The site I'm building at the moment is made of two main parts: The side which the general public can access, and the admin side which only authorised people can access.

It's built with basic templating such that the different sections are accessed as follow (Using RewriteRules).

Public:
`http://localhost/about` should be rewritten to `http://localhost/index.php?page=about`

Admin:
`http://localhost/admin/manage-users` should be rewritten to `http://localhost/admin/index.php?page=manage-users`

All URLs only ever have one argument. That is, public will always be localhost/PAGE and admin will always be localhost/admin/PAGE.

At the moment, I have the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^admin/([^/.]+)/?$ /admin/index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

This seems to work properly when you construct the URL correctly. For example, if I navigate to `localhost/about` or `localhost/admin/manage-users` both pages load correctly. But if I go to `localhost/about/blah` or `localhost/admin/manage-users/blah`, the pages load, however the CSS is non-existant. Looking at the developer tools in Chrome, it appears that this is because it's trying to load the CSS file from the directories `localhost/about/css/` and `localhost/admin/css/` respectively, due to the style sheet being linked to the page with a relative path. (In reality, `localhost/css/` is the directory it is actually located in.)

So even though the RedirectRule ignores any extra arguments in the URL, it is trying to load relative paths with respect to the last "directory" provided in the URL.

Is there any way to completely ignore any extra `../..` arguments? Or, even better, trigger a 404 when too many arguments are provided?

**UPDATE:** I have just discovered that the problem is actually a lot more complex than I previously thought. As my pages only had dummy data to test out the templating files, I didn't notice it until now.

It appears than when you navigate to `localhost/admin` or `localhost/admin/manage-users` it is loading from the `http://localhost/admin/index.php` file, but when you navigate to `localhost/admin/manage-users/blah` is reverts back to loading the `http://localhost/index.php` file. This makes me think that there is something I need to change in the RewriteRule, though I have no idea what.

Comment: Just make the CSS relative to the document root, so start it with a `/`.

Comment: That would definitely fix the issue, however, if this is happening with one CSS file, then it's going to happen with every link, everywhere throughout the site. And there are a LOT of links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better in long term to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

But in order to avoid making changes to your website in-mass you can use these rules to fix your css/js/images links:

```
RewriteEngine on

# fix CSS/js/images links
RewriteRule (?:^|/)((?:css|js|images)/.+)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^admin/([^.]+)/?$ /admin/index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Don't forget to replace first rule with your actual css/js/images directories.

Comment: That could work, though I realised the situation is worse than I thought. See update above. Thanks :)

Comment: ok check updated answer now for your complete & corrected .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks, that's almost perfect. Only thing is, now if you navigate to `http://localhost/admin/manage-users/blah` it will try and load `http://localhost/admin/index.php?page=manage-users/blah`. Obviously I can easily explode on '/' within the template, to get the actual page name by itself, so worst come to worst I will do that. But is there a way to just grab the first part within the htaccess file?

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, it's probably better to leave it like it is, and throw a 404 from the index file if the page doesn't exist. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to either make all of your links absolute URLs (e.g. `href="/css/style.css"`) or add a relative URL base to the header of your page:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: Would this apply to all links? Whether it be CSS/JS links or hyperlinks?

Comment: I realised the situation is worse than I thought. See update above. Thanks :)